# What is my default document root directory?

Tags: directory, root, default, document

What is my default document root directory and how do I find it ?
Allow me to explain I'm trying to set up CMS on my laptop so I'm following [these](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/install-and-configure-grav-cms-on-ubuntu-16-04/) instructions.
In the point where it says to "Installing Grav CMS" the first command is `cd /var/www/html/` but when I type it in the terminal it says no such directory I checked it by hand and it is right, there isn't one ... so how can I find it?

Comment: In what context? For an Apache server? Some other server software?

Comment: I don't know. Isn't it the place where you usually put your documents? How could somebody from the Internet know where you are accustomed to put your documents? If you mean the default value for `DocumentRoot` in an Apache HTTP Server configuration file just say so.

Comment: "default document root" is a term I've only seen used in the context of server software. On an Ubuntu system, your documents are generally stored in `~/Documents` (that is, `/home/$USER/Documents`), but if you're talking about a "document root" directory for a server, it will be a different location... perhaps something like `/home/www/server.name`. Knowing why and what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: @NickWeinberg here's an explanation :)

Comment: There missing a step. Just create that directory and go further.

Comment: There are and other mistakes. For example `cd /var/www/html/sudo git clone https://github.com/getgrav/grav.git`. These are two separate commands: 1) `cd /var/www/html/` and 2) `sudo git clone https://github.com/getgrav/grav.git`.